# Uber API integration

Tags: uber-api

Im curious as to how advanced the API is and what are my options when creating the API? My company is creating an online concierge for Vegas and I wanted to use Uber API for pickup and dropoffs to nightlife venues.

Comment: Services include shows, tours, concerts, nightclubs, gentleman clubs etc..

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the Uber developer website: https://developer.uber.com/ which lists different use cases, solutions, showcases, etc. To begin integrating look at the 'docs' section.

StackOverflow should be for a specific technical coding questions. If you have anything like that, please follow up with a new question.